# Prime ideals in rings of differential equations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations, commutative-algebra

Assume I have two index sets $I, J$ of arbitrary (finite or infinite, equal or not equal) cardinality. Let $R$ be a ring (associative, commutative, unitary).

Let $S:= R(x_{j_{1}},f_{i_{1}},\frac{d^{n}f_{i_{2}}}{dx_{j_{2}}^{n}})_{i_{1},i_{2}\in I,j_{1},j_{2}\in J}$. Let $e_{1},e_{2}$ be two differential equations in $S$ so that $e_{1}\Rightarrow e_{2}$.

Assume $(e_{2})$ is a prime ideal in $S$. Does the same hold for $(e_{1})$ as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a counterexample myself: Take $e_{1}=e_{2}^{2}$ and make $R$ an integral domain.